# CSS Pixel/Computer like Font - Courier New for example

Tags: html, css, fonts, styles, font-family

I would like to use a font like on the following picture.

http://i.minus.com/ibinuNBMiT8CSk.jpg

[image]

This font is Courier regular. But as soon as I try to use it on a webpage it is smooth.

```
font-family: 'Courier', monospace;
font-smooth: never;
-webkit-font-smoothing : none;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried `font-family: courier;`? http://jsfiddle.net/8Vw6T/

Comment: yeah I have, it´s the same.

Comment: It is NOT a standard and should NOT be used. Since 2002, it is removed from this specification. Also for webkit it is a non-standard. Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @dTDesign ok, any Idea how I get the Font pixel like ? Is there any web font which doesn´t get smoothed ?

Comment: There are lots of those pixel style fonts to be found on the web. Just search for bitmap font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Silkscreen

A really classic 8-bit font

http://www.dafont.com/silkscreen.font

[image: font example]

Comment: thats what I was looking for, thank you. Where do I find the licence of this font?

Comment: Happy to help :) I don't think you have to have a license for it.. you can download it free off that link.